# How to share css and js files across projects in the same solution?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to share  css, js and aspx fils across the projects? I ahve to keep all the common files in one project and refer these in other projects in the same solution. Please let me know how I can share the files across the projects in the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have one common project, call it something like Shared or Utilities (make sure it's a web project). Put your files in that project, then use the URL of that project + the path to the file to reference them in your other projects, something like:

http://mysharedproject.co.uk/content/site.css

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [ASP.Net MVC Portable Areas](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/) for that. With portable areas you can embed scripts and css in your DLL files and reuse them across applications.